# Files on Kali Linux aren't showing up

Tags: command-line

I am new to Kali Linux. I was moving and organizing files, and Kali Linux isn't listing files I have extracted and moved into /Documents/, but they are physically there in the GUI. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. We are sorry, Kali-Linux is off-topic. You can use https://forums.kali.org/ but Kali Linux is intended for experienced GNU/Linux users and users are expected to fix their own problems, and only when that fails to have them ask a question with a well-documented problem.    (see the on-topic link for the alternate SE *Unix & Linux* site).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you might've hidden the files while copying and moving them, try

> ls -l/Documents

and that will show the hidden files, you should be able to see them now.

Comment: FYI:  I don't think the "-l" to view directory in long form will help much.. "-a" will list all files (inc. invisible), if you want both long & all it's "-al" or "-la"....  but I'm not sure that's the OP's issue (OP = original poster)